# Questions regarding printing a webpage into PDF and margins

Tags: pdf, printing, printer

I want to print some pages on a website. I am planning to do this by first printing the website into a pdf file, then printing the pdf file itself.

However, when printing the website into a pdf file, I want the odd numbered pages and even numbered pages to have different margins. How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save two versions of the website as PDF -- one with one size margins and one with the other size margins.

Save them with different identifiable names.

Then print the even pages of the one size margin, and then print the odd pages of the other size margins.

I know some browsers (like Chrome) allow you to change the margin size when "printing" to pdf.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Is there a way for me to combine the even pages and odd pages of a PDF file? Like for instance if there are two PDFs, PDF A and PDF B, then for the even page of PDF C, I have the even pages of PDF A and for the odd pages of PDF C, I have the odd pages of PDF B.

Comment: You can click and drag PDF pages into each other if you are using Mac OS X's Preview app; Preview is by far the best app for PDF manipulation that I have used. I'm not sure what type of machine you're using for this task, but there are also some websites that do this (LINK https://www.google.com/search?&q=combine+even+pages+of+one+PDF+with+odd+pages+of+different+PDF&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) I'm not sure how sensitive the info in your PDF is though. If you're really desperate,  print out as mentioned in my answer, then put them in the proper order manually, then scan them to create a new PDF.

Comment: Thank you! Luckily, I'm using a MacBook so I guess I'll use preview! :)